# Java random character generated then output in the text attribute of a TextView element in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, random

I am trying to get a random character generated from a String array and then set it as the text for a TextView element. Currently the IDE does not show any syntax or logic errors but the app crashes when run on my phone.

I have set the random generation to take place when the Start button is pressed.

```
public void startGame (View starGame) { //ISOLATE RANDOM FUNCTION TO SEE IF IT WORKED OR NOT
    String characterString = "ABCDE";
    Random rnd = new Random();
    char note = characterString.charAt(rnd.nextInt(characterString.length()));
    TextView noteQuestion = findViewById(R.id.CharacterOutput); 
    noteQuestion.setText(note); //set message string as textView text
}
```

This is the code in the main activity and the button has the onClick set to startGame.

Comment: Open Logcat in android studio and it should show the crash log

Comment: Try `noteQuestion.setText(String.valueOf(note))` since you are trying to set a char to textview. you can set string to setText